# Fortran calculate sum of floating numbers not getting exact precision

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am new to Fortran90 , I have write a simple program to add two floating point numbers as follows:

```
program Numbers_sum

  implicit none

  REAL :: sum
  sum = 1.6+2
  print*,"Sum =", sum
  end
```

I am getting the answer as `Sum = 3.5999999`

Why it is not getting `3.6`. How Can I make this program to get the exact answer?? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @francescalus nope it is not. Just read carefully. It is Fortran. I tried C++ and Python also no such issue!!

Comment: This is a question about floating point numbers.  There is a difference, perhaps, between what happens in C and Python, but you are using what is likely to be a single precision IEEE number rather than double.  Fundamentally, you'll need to understand that other question/answers before Fortran becomes important: even `1.6d0+2d0` will not give you `3.6`.

Comment: @francescalus ok I agree. But then why C++ and Python gives the correct answer as 3.6 insted of 3.5999999.?????????

Comment: In double precision 1.6+2 is much closer to 3.6 than the same in single precision.  It could just be a formatting thing (I'm not sufficiently familiar with those languages) rather than an exact representation.

Comment: @francescalus ok buddy. Is there any way in Fortran to approximate my sum? I mean to make it 3.6? Please guide me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76053/discussion-between-santhucool-and-francescalus).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to write 3.6 in base 2 with finite digits. It's `2 + 1 + 1/2 + 1/16 + ...`

You can, however, hide the rounding error by selecting proper formatting:

```
write(*, '(F11.6)') sum
```

If you want to calculate in higher precision, you could use this:

```
REAL(KIND=8) :: var
```

Or, if you want to be really proper:

```
program numbers_sum
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(P=12)
  real(kind=dp) :: sum1
  sum1 = 1.6_dp + 2
  print *, "Sum = ", sum1
end
```

But even this won't eliminate the rounding completely.

Cheers

Comment: I am getting errors : sum.for: In program `numbers_sum':
sum.for:3:
     integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(P=12)
     ^
Fortran 90 feature at (^) unsupported
sum.for:3:
     integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(P=12)
                                ^
Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `selected_real_kind' at (^) [initi
ally seen at (^)]
sum.for:3:
     integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(P=12)
                                                   ^
...