# Increasing accuracy of “sum()” command in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I am trying to perform summation of an array.

There are 1024 elements in that array and on applying the command "sum(a(:))", where a(:) is the array, I get the answer 1981.9072.

If I do the same summation of 1024 elements in Excel sheet the answer is 1981.93530 which is the right answer. So, a difference of 0.0281 is observed between the above two values. As I increase the number of elements in a(:) the difference in value obtained from "sum()" and Excel sheet increases.

I think the "sum()" value is different due to rounding off error. How do I get the true value (Excel value) using "sum()" without any rounding off error ?

Comment: What makes you think Excel is correct and your program is wrong? Are you familiar with how IEEE-754 numbers work? Have you read this article: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html ?

Comment: What is the type of `a`'s elements? Are you using `real` or `double` or a different type? Are you using the `kind()` specifier?

Comment: Lets say all the elements of a(:) are 1.93548369. Then the sum should be = 1.93548369*1024=1981.19353 ( which is given by excel) and that given by sum(a(:))=1981.9072

Comment: The variable is real and defined as "REAL(4)"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: A more exact duplicate link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823429/fortran-calculate-sum-of-floating-numbers-not-getting-exact-precision

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Fortran 90 is just one particular very old version of the standard.

Answer (score 1):

`REAL(4)` is a 32-bit IEEE-754 floating-point number **which is imprecise**.

You **absolutely need to** read and understand this important QA on the matter: [Why are floating point numbers inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

Here's a page on the same topic from the GCC Fortran compiler docs: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/g77/Floating_002dpoint-Errors.html

You need to change the type of `a` to `REAL(8)` - but note that even if you do, the sum still won't be completely accurate (it will just be *less inaccurate*).

---

This can be reproduced consistently in any language that implements IEEE-754 32-bit floating-point numbers, like C# (I'm using C# as I don't have access to a Fortran90 compiler right now):

```
static void Main()
{
    Single t = 0f;

    for( Int32 i = 0; i < 1024; i++ )
    {
        t += 1.93548369f; // This is a 32-bit float literal
    }

    Console.WriteLine( t ); // "1981.9072"
}
```

If you sum the numbers using a double-precision (64-bit) floating number type you get the same result as Excel:

```
static void Main()
{
    Double d = 0d;

    for( Int32 i = 0; i < 1024; i++ )
    {
        d += 1.93548369d; // This is a 64-bit float literal
    }

    Console.WriteLine( d ); // "1981.935302734375" --> "1981.9350"
}
```

If you want an **accurate** and **precise** answer then you need to use a data-type that doesn't use IEEE-754 - I'm not a Fortran user so I don't know what/if Fortran's equivalent of C#'s `Decimal` is, but when I do the calculation with `Decimal` I get `1981.93529856` which is different to Excel's answer (this is because Excel uses 64-bit IEEE-754 instead of a real Decimal type):

```
static void Main()
{
    Decimal dec = 0M;
    
    for( Int32 i = 0; i < 1024; i++ )
    {
        dec += 1.93548369M; // This is a decimal literal, note the `M`.
    }

    Console.WriteLine( dec ); // "1981.93529856" --> "1981.9352"
}
```

Comment: REAL(4) *might* be 32-bit IEEE-754 floating-point or could be anything else. It does not have to exist at all. REAL(8) *might* be 64-bit IEEE-754 floating-point or could be anything else.  It does not have to exist at all. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter I strongly suggest **NOT** to use magic numbers like 4 or 8 for kind numbers.

Comment: Also be aware that your link goes to the manual of g77 that wasn't even a Fortran 90 compiler and, in particular, kinds 4 and 8 did **NOT** exist there. g77 used kind numbers 1 and 2 for these (as you can easily see yourself in your link).

Comment: It would be very good if you could edit your answer to reflect the information Vladimit has provided

Comment: @IanBush I am not a Fortran expert so I'm wary of being even more incorrect - both you and Vladimir have sufficient SO reputation to edit my answer on my behalf.

Comment: The `sum` intrinsic is most often implemented via the naive and grade-school algorithm of well simply adding the individual elements up without consideration of round-off error.  Why?  Because this is fast.  If you want a possibly more accurate summation,then search for **Kahan summation** or **summation with carry**.  If you implement this algorithm you absolutely want to avoid compiler options that cause the compiler to violate Fortran's expression evaluation rules.